# Jenkins-pipeline replaces variable with new value '-1' while sorting HashMap

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

First, I create a Map and fill it with values. Then I want to sort the map by value. And I use the sort method as in the example.
In my IDE in the console, I see that the behavior of the program corresponds to my expectations.

However, when I run the program from the groovy pipeline, an inexplicable thing happens after sorting. Due to the flexible typing Map is replaced by a number.

```
node("Linux_Default") {
    Map painters = ["Rubens": 1, "Bosch": 2, "Repin": 5, "DaVinci": 10] as HashMap<String, Integer>
    println('unordered')
    for (String i : painters) {
        println('* ' + i)
    }

    def sortedPainters = painters.sort(){ a, b -> b.value <=> a.value }
    try {
        println('ordered')
        for (String i : sortedPainters) {
            println('* ' + i)
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println(e.toString())
    }
}
```

Output from IDE

```
unordered
* Rubens=1
* Bosch=2
* Repin=5
* DaVinci=10
ordered
* DaVinci=10
* Repin=5
* Bosch=2
* Rubens=1
```

Output from pipeline console

```
Running in Durability level: PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED
Running on jenkins-agent-linux-008 in /u01/jenkins_slave/workspace/KMD/maps_sort_test
unordered
* Rubens=1
* Bosch=2
* Repin=5
* DaVinci=10
ordered
* -1
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some methods are not processed well under CPS in Jenkins with custom closures. The solution is to isolate the problematic code in a `@NonCPS` closure like:

```
@NonCPS
def getSorted(def map) {
    map.sort(){ a, b -> b.value <=> a.value }
}
```

Then you'll see `def sortedPainters = getSorted(painters)` returns a sorted map rather than a strange scalar.

See also:

[Jenkins sort method behaviour not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946282/jenkins-sort-method-behaviour-not-as-expected)

[pipeline groovy script - Sort a list with custom comparator or closure not sorting](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44924)